# Belongs to two columns laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have tables:

attributes: 
- id - id of attribute 
- name - name of attribute

attributes_relations: 
- id -id of relation 
- attribute_id - current attribute id 
- attribute_relation_id - relation of this current attribute id with other from table attributes

In model Attribute I have relation:

```
public function attributerelation()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\AttributeRelation');
}
```

But in model AttributeRelation I have:

```
public function attribute_rel()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Attribute', 'attribute_relation_id');
}
```

I need belongs this with two columns: attribute_id and attribute_relation_id.

Becuase if I call:

```
$attribute->attributerelation->attribute_rel->name
```

This was working only for related attribute.

Comment: Check the docs about how to implement a many-to-many relation correctly: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I don't need manyToMany. I can have only one relation with attribute.

Comment: "relation of this current attribute id with other from table attributes" - it seems to me that one attribute can be linked to multiple attributes. If it wasn't many-to-many, it would be enough to just have `related_attribute_id` foreign key in attributes table, so why do you need attributes_relations table?

Comment: Ok how I can then get collection of column bind_attribute_id, if I create relation column on attribute?

Comment: I have no idea what this column is, it's not mentioned in your post...